# Angular Cordova push data gone after reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, session

im new with angular, and i want create apps that store cart data to sesssion using push, 
but when i reloading the page, the data session was gone, not like in the php $_SESSION,

heres my code

```
cartObj.cart.push( { "cart_item_id": id , "cart_item_image": image , "cart_item_name": name , "cart_item_price": price , "cart_item_qty": qty } );
```

how to make the cart data is store in session, 
i'l try using local storage but it not work either

```
localStorage.setItem('cart_item_name', name);
```

in my controller

```
$scope.name= localStorage.getItem('cart_item_name');
```

im new here, hope someone care to answer and explain slowly,

thanks

edit

this my controller

```
.controller('keranjangBelanjaCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','sharedCartService','$ionicPopup','$state', // TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams,sharedCartService,$ionicPopup,$state) {

    //onload event-- to set the values
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    $scope.name= localStorage.getItem("cart_item_name");



    });
```

this my view

```
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

solved with

```
.controller('keranjangBelanjaCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','sharedCartService','$ionicPopup','$state', // TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams,sharedCartService,$ionicPopup,$state) {

    $scope.name= localStorage.getItem("cart_item_name");





    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store the whole object in localstorage just Id of your cart item and get your cart item later by that Id. Currently you are storing just name. Item will be stored in localstorage until someone not remove it.

```
localStorage.setItem("cartId", id)
```

And get

```
localStorage.getItem("id") || 'null'
```

Comment: its gone when i reload the page, seem not storing in session,

Comment: it can't be. it's not session. how's your code look like? you can test in dev tools console by typing localStorage.setItem("id",1) and get it by localStorage.getItem("id") and you will have 1. it can depends on your browser also.

Comment: yeah, its work in console, so the problem is in mu controller right?

Comment: has to be share your code so i can try to help you.

Comment: yeah, i update the answer above, so other reader may read my post and found the solution,